# How to fix string out of index range when customizing looping "input()" in python?

Tags: python, input, user-input, continue, stringindexoutofbounds

I'm experimenting with the `input()` function. I'm trying to make the code to loop for user input and continue or break the loop based on the user input.

```
while True:
    line = input("> ")
    if line[0] == "#" :
        continue
    if line == "done" :
        break
    print(line)
print('Done!')
```

I want to try to make the code to continue loop after an input "#" is written, but I'm having trouble when the user input "" a blank text (string index out of range).

How do I fix this and what if I want the continue to be when user input " #" instead? as in:

```
while True:
    line = input("> ")
    if line[1] == "#" :
        continue
    if line == "done" :
        break
    print(line)
print('Done!')
```

Comment: 1) You check for the string's length first. 2) Call `.strip()`. Alternatively, use `if "#" in line:`

Comment: The popular coding pattern for ensuring line is not blank before indexing into it is with an *and* condition i.e.  `if line and line[1] == "#" :`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Manage to avoid this issue by first checking if index range is met first before indexing.

```
while True:
    line = input("> ")
    if len(line) == 0 : # check if blank
        print('please input something')
        continue
    if len(line) >= 2 : # check if index is in range
        if line[1] == '#' :
            continue
    if line == "done" :
        break
    print(line)
print('Done!')
```

I actually want to trigger the condition if the position of '#' are in line[1] or in any line[] like " #HelloWorld" or " # Something". Thanks for the effort to write some method I can use, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    line = input("> ")
    if line == "#": # removed '[0]'
        continue
    if line == "done":
        break
print(line)        
print('Done!')
```

I just removed the '[0]' list index, which is not needed as `line` is just a variable that holds the value of user input